# How to use regex to only show match at beginning of string

Tags: regex

I am trying to use regex on this test text:

```
www.demo.comhttp://foo.co.uk/
http://regexr.com/foo.html?q=bar
```

I want it to only match 'http://' in the beginning of the string. I tried

```
^http:\/\/
```

and

```
^(http:\/\/)
```

and

```
(http:\/\/)\B
```

and neither worked. What am I doing wrong (I'm not very good at regex and I'm trying to learn)

Comment: What regex tool are you using? `^http:\/\/` should work with `m` (MULTILINE) flag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More likely you have omitted the multi-line flag :

```
/^http:\/\//m
```

Comment: yep, that did it. Thanks!